# kableExtra : add a footnote to a rowname [kableExtra, Rmd]

Tags: r, r-markdown, kableextra

I'm using the `kableExtra` library with R Markdown, I would like to add footnotes to the row labels (and secondary, to other cells).
How can I do that ?

Data example below:

```
library(kableExtra)
tab = data.frame(matrix(NA, 5,5))
rownames(tab) = paste("info", 1:5)
kable(tab)
```

I want to add a footnote to `info 1`, the label of the 1st line (for example).

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use `footnote`from `kableExtra`:

```
dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:5]
footnote(knitr::kable(dt, "html"), alphabet = c("Note a", "Note b"))
```